# jquery looping through elements to dynamically add ids .?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to add ids to all my wanted elements. It's not working and showing any error in console.

I want jQuery to loop through all my `.mm` elements and add id with respect to their orders and add ids to their child `.cards` too like shown below

**JQUERY**

```
//assigning ids codes on page load
    var lists = $("body > div.mm");
    $.each(lists,function( index, value ){
        var cards = lists[index].children();
        lists[index].setAttribute("id", "div"+index);
        $.each(cards,function(index,value){
            cards[index].setAttribute("id", "card"+index);
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
   <body>
        <div class='span'>
            <div class="list">
                <h1 contenteditable="true">DO</h1>
                <div class='mm' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                    <span draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class='card' contenteditable="true">card1</span>
                </div>
                    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span class="newCard" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list">
                    <h1 contenteditable="true">UNDER PROGRESS</h1>
                    <div class='mm' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                        <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                        <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                        <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                        <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                        <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="newCard" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                    <h1 contenteditable="true">COMPLETED</h1>
                <div class='mm' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                </div>
                    <span class="newCard" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
            </div>
            <div class="nlist" contenteditable="true">
                ADD NEW LIST
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</div>
</html>
```

> NOT WORKING DONT KNOW WHY I WANT TO LOOP THROUGH all .mm 's and .cards two add ids like below.

```
   <body>
        <div class='span'>
            <div class="list">
                <h1 contenteditable="true">DO</h1>
                <div id='div1' class='mm' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                </div>
                    <span id='card1' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span id='card2' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span id='card3' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span id='card4' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span id='card5' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span id='card6' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span id='card7' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    <span class="newCard" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list">
                    <h1 contenteditable="true">UNDER PROGRESS</h1>
                    <div id='div2' class='mm' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <span id='card8' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                        <span id='card9' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                        <span id='card10' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                        <span id='card11' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                        <span id='card12' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                        <span id='card13' class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="newCard" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                    <h1 contenteditable="true">COMPLETED</h1>
                <div id='div3' class='mm' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                </div>
                    <span class="newCard" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
            </div>
            <div class="nlist" contenteditable="true">
                ADD NEW LIST
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: in your example `.mm` does not contain any `.Card`, it appears that one `.mm` does contain a `.card`.

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted to reproduce your desired output.  A quick little `$.each()` allows us to get the indexes we need to produce an `id` for each element.  Because `id` needs to be unique you must loop through every instance of the target element one time without resetting your index.

```js
//run through the .mm's
$("div.mm").each(function(idx, elem){
  $(elem).attr("id", `div${idx+1}`);
});
//run through the .Card's
$("span.Card").each(function(idx, elem){
  $(elem).attr("id", `card${idx+1}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='span'>
  <div class="list">
    <h1 contenteditable="true">DO</h1>
    <div class='mm' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <span draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class='card' contenteditable="true">card1</span>
    </div>
    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
    <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
    <span class="newCard" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <h1 contenteditable="true">UNDER PROGRESS</h1>
    <div class='mm' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
      <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
      <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
      <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
      <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
      <span class="Card" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
    </div>
    <span class="newCard" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <h1 contenteditable="true">COMPLETED</h1>
    <div class='mm' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </div>
    <span class="newCard" contenteditable="true">+ ADD CARD</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nlist" contenteditable="true">
    ADD NEW LIST
  </div>
</div>
```